# displaying spanish version of date while using transcribe

Tags: multi-language, transcribe, entry-date

I am using transcribe and I was wondering if there is a way to display the entry_date in spanish.

I could probably build a plugin that captures the entry date and returns the appropriate format based on transcribe's current language session, but I was wondering if there is anything out there first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to add some transcribe variables so you can generate language codes.
make on like transcribe_lang_country with the value "en" and one like transcribe_lang_language with the value "US" (this is for the american english language version. I don't know the spanish ones)

then let the locale be determined by the browser by adding the country variable to the html:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="{transcribe_lang_country}">
```

This would let the browser render the time notation in the proper format.
Mind you; EE wil render the date notation based upon the language settings of the logged in user. So to check if it works use another browser where you are not logged in.

Another nice little trick is when you are using validationengine on your forms you can get the error messages easily in the proper language by calling the right locale {transcribe_lang_country}_{transcribe_lang_language}, which will render as en_US

there is also the date/time convert addon from Carl Crawley that could help: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/date-time-language-converter

Comment: I've not used validationengine, but I don't see the {transcribe_lang_...} variables/tags in Transcribe's docs. You can always create them as strings.
Crawley's add-on requires you to have the locale you want (in this case Spanish) installed on your webserver, which you may or may not be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an add-on to do this and more but it's still in beta. If the code can help you, help yourself: https://github.com/tfitzgeraldca/Polyglot Any feedback is welcome.